# changed the iptables configuration by mistake and want to revoke it

Tags: iptables

I happened to reset the `iptables` configuration with the following command.

`$iptables -F`

But fortunately I didn't save it yet, so I just would like to find out how not to save the change.

Anyone with the solution?

Comment: If you resetted the configuration ... Then there are no changes that could be saved... then I don't really get what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command:

```
iptables --flush
```

is only temporary. To make it permanent your do:

```
iptables-save
```

Since you haven't done so it's ok

Comment: If I execute `iptables-save` and then `iptables-restore`, will i be going back to the original state then?

Comment: Ok, do `sudo systemctl retart iptables` and lets see what it holds